# How to tell which props come from which library in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am a React beginner and have the assignment to understand and refactor/enhance legacy code. I observed that most of the components and containers have a lot of props that just "magically" appear and are usable.

Of course, props are populated by certain libraries rather than magic, but for someone who hasn't got enough knowledge about all the libraries that are used in a project, understanding the source of the props in a single component is cumbersome; especially if the component has LOTS of imports.

Look at this example:

```
const { error, location, submitting, handleSubmit, intl: { formatMessage } } = this.props
```

Now, I have figured out by checking one-by-one and googling that `location` comes from `react-router` library, `intl` comes from `react-intl` and the remaining come from `redux-form`. Is there an easier way to understand which prop is populated by which library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain JS there's no other way apart from following the props back up through the component tree and working out where they got injected. Either that, or just having knowledge of prop naming by common libs that you pick up with experience.

You might be working with a poorly architected project. Best practice is to only pass library props between components one level, i.e. from container to component. They shouldn't be handed from component to component to component, since it makes the architecture too brittle and hard to understand.

If however you're using some sort of type sytem (Flow or TypeScript) it can be possible to indicate the type of props, e.g.

```
import type { Location } from 'react-router'

type Props = {
  location: Location,
}
```